# Where in this web can I post what I think rather than ask about bitcoin

Tags: forum

I would like to know where can I post What I think and have a discussion on Bitcoin issues rather than ask/answer questions, or is this just an ask and answer area?

Comment: There's forum just google 'bitcoin talk'

Comment: Stackexchange is a question&answer platform. So, you can write what you think in answers that fit the questions asked. ;) Check out [about] for a quick overview what Stackexchange is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about this web site should be asked on [meta]

Answer (score 5):

**Forums I participate in**

[bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/)

[cryptocointalk](https://cryptocointalk.com/)

[cryptocrypt](https://cryptocrypt.org/)

[Bitcoin Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/)

[Bitcoinfoundation forum](https://bitcoinfoundation.org/forum/)

**Google Search**

[bitcoinforum](https://www.bitcoinforum.com/)

[ecoiner](https://ecoiner.org)

[coinboards](http://www.coinboards.org/)

[bitcointrading forum](http://www.bitcointrading.com/forum/index.php)

[coinforum.ca](https://www.coinforum.ca/)

There's bucket loads of forums out there, not to mention IRC Channells where you can find People 24 hours a day to talk live to about bitcoins

[IRC channels](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/IRC_channels)

I think the harder question will be where to start ;) good luck